# Reading a pickle file (PANDAS Python Data Frame) in R

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

Is there an easy way to read pickle files (.pkl) from Pandas Dataframe into R?

One possibility is to export to CSV and have R read the CSV but that seems really cumbersome for me because my dataframes are rather large. Is there an easier way to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: You can also look into `fread` from the `data.table` package. It reads in csv files substantially faster than base R (which is really slow). Quick test with a 150 MB csv file shows 11 seconds with `read.csv` and 2 seconds with `fread`.

Comment: Why not just store in a database like SQLite that both R and Python can read/write to? In fact, that's the purpose of RDMS to serve as central repository for end use programs.

Comment: @Parfait If the data is large, storing the data into an RDMS and especially serializing it back out to R will be (relatively slow).  Just my observations re: RDMS speed for this sort of operation.  In my experience, streaming as mentioned by Laterrow and in my answer will turn out to be much faster in most cases with large datasets.  Using rpy2 might turn out to be slower than streaming - but it has the advantage (like RDMS) of keeping the data structured as it goes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Edit: If you can install and use the {reticulate} package, then this answer is probably outdated.  See the other answers below for an easier path.

You could load the pickle in python and then export it to R via the python package `rpy2` (or similar).  Once you've done so, your data will exist in an R session linked to python.  I suspect that what you'd want to do next would be to use that session to call R and saveRDS to a file or RAM disk.  Then in RStudio you can read that file back in.  Look at the R packages `rJython` and `rPython` for ways in which you could trigger the python commands from R.

Alternatively, you could write a simple python script to load your data in Python (probably using one of the R packages noted above) and write a formatted data stream to stdout.  Then that entire system call to the script (including the argument that specifies your pickle) can use used as an argument to `fread` in the R package `data.table`.  Alternatively, if you wanted to keep to standard functions, you could use combination of `system(..., intern=TRUE)` and `read.table`.

As usual, there are /many/ ways to skin this particular cat.  The basic steps are:

1. Load the data in python
2. Express the data to R (e.g., exporting the object via rpy2 or writing formatted text to stdout with R ready to receive it on the other end)
3. Serialize the expressed data in R to an internal data representation  (e.g., exporting the object via rpy2 or `fread`)
4. (optional) Make the data in that session of R accessible to another R session (i.e., the step to close the loop with rpy2, or if you've been using `fread` then you're already done).

Comment: Interesting, thanks! How would I go about exporting `r_dataframe` and opening it in say, Rstudio?

Comment: I expanded on your options above.

Comment: P.s. with {reticulate} this got a ton easier to manage entirely from the R side... and works particularly well in RStudio.

Answer (score 54):

[Reticulate](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate) was quite easy and super smooth as suggested by russellpierce in the comments.

```
install.packages('reticulate')
```

After which I created a Python script like this from examples given in their documentation.

Python file:

```
import pandas as pd

def read_pickle_file(file):
    pickle_data = pd.read_pickle(file)
    return pickle_data
```

And then my R file looked like:

```
require("reticulate")

source_python("pickle_reader.py")
pickle_data <- read_pickle_file("C:/tsa/dataset.pickle")
```

This gave me all my data in R stored earlier in pickle format.

You can also do this all in-line in R without leaving your R editor (provided your system python can reach pandas)... e.g.

```
library(reticulate)
pd <- import("pandas")
pickle_data <- pd$read_pickle("dataset.pickle")
```

Comment: Trying this and getting Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
  KeyError: 'max_depth' - familiar to anyone?

Comment: You can just do...

```
library(reticulate)
pd <- import("pandas")
pickle_data <- pd$read_pickle("dataset.pickle")
```

Answer (score 6):

To add to the answer above:  you might need to point to a different conda env to get to pandas:

```
use_condaenv("name_of_conda_env", conda = "<<result_of `which conda`>>")
pd <- import('pandas')

df <- pd$read_pickle(paste0(outdir, "df.pkl"))
```

Answer (score 2):

[`reticulate::py_load_object(filename)`](https://rdrr.io/cran/reticulate/man/py_save_object.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33964411)

Comment: It's a piece of code that explicitly answers the question, self sufficiently. The link is just bonus.