# reticulate package - change python version

Tags: python, r

I am trying to load a dataset in pickle format into R. 
I found the package "reticulate" thanks to this question:

[Reading a pickle file (PANDAS Python Data Frame) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121192/reading-a-pickle-file-pandas-python-data-frame-in-r)

This is my Python file called "pickle_reader.py"

```
def read_pickle_file(file):
    pickle_data = pd.read_pickle(file)
    return pickle_data
```

This is my R code:

```
library(reticulate)
use_python("/usr/bin/python3", required = T)
source_python("pickle_reader.py")
pickle_data <- read_pickle_file("/path/to/file.pkl")
```

The following error message comes up in R:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 4

Detailed traceback: 
  File "<string>", line 11, in read_pickle_file
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py", line 60, in read_pickle
    return try_read(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py", line 57, in try_read
    return pc.load(fh, encoding=encoding, compat=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/compat/pickle_compat.py", line 116, in load
    return up.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 892, in load_proto
    raise ValueError, "unsupported pickle protocol: %d" % proto
```

So it seems that the error occurs because the pickle protocol cannot be handled by Python 2.7. Therefore I use the line

```
use_python("/usr/bin/python3", required = T)
```

above. But it seems to have no effect. The output of `py_discover_config()` is:

```
python:         /usr/bin/python3
libpython:      /usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5.so
pythonhome:     /usr:/usr
version:        3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
numpy:          /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.14.2

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python function
```

The output of `py_config()` is:

```
python:         /usr/bin/python
libpython:      /usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so
pythonhome:     /usr:/usr
version:        2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
numpy:          /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.11.0

python versions found: 
 /usr/bin/python
 /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: How was the pickle originally created? You can set *protocol* in [`DataFrame.to_pickle`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle). By the way for such a small Python script, just have `reticulate` load pandas and run the `read_pickle` call.

Comment: I don't know. I didn't create the pickle myself.

Comment: Did you ever successfully load the pickle in Python -NOT in R?

Comment: No, this is the first time I am using it.

Comment: Then give it a try on Python end. Check the source and creator of that file.